# Compare an array to a string and replace all items found in the array with a common character in the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have a string of text with 100 different "keys" between some characters `« »` and an array containing the `UsedKeys`. I'm trying to compare the string `str` to the array and replace all keys found in the `UsedKey` array with check mark character. I'm still very new to loops as well as javascript in general, and I can't seem to get the script to replace any of the keys except for the last one in the array. In this case that would be `«SPLXVIII»`.

I also have a second array called `AllKeys` which I'd like to use in order to hide all of the non-used keys. I'm certain I'd have to find the difference between the two arrays (`UsedKeys` and `AllKeys`), i'm just not quite sure how.

Questions:

1) How can I replace all of the keys in the UsedKey array?

2) How can I hide all of the other keys in the string that aren't in the UsedKey array?

```
function replace() {
var str = ("«SPII» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPIV» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPVI» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPVIII» Free Water<br>«SPX» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPXII» Free Squishy<br>«SPXIV» Free Fast Pass Token (Redeem at thundershack)<br>«SPXVI» Free Hot Cheetos<br>«SPXVIII» Free Fast Pass Token (Redeem at thundershack)<br>«SPXX» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPXXII» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPXXIV» Free Grab Bag Item (it could be anything)<br>«SPXXVI» Thundershack Gift Card<br>«SPXXVIII» Free Sour Punch Stick<br>«SPXXX» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPXXXII» 50% Off Thundershack 1 item<br>«SPXXXIV» Free Grab Bag Item (it could be anything)<br>«SPXXXVI» Thunder Cash<br>«SPXXXVIII» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPXL» WIS Lanyard and Id Pouch<br>«SPXLII» Free Fast Pass Token (Redeem at thundershack)<br>«SPXLIV» Free Soda<br>«SPXLVI» Free Sour Punch Stick<br>«SPXLVIII» Free Grab Bag Item (it could be anything)<br>«SPL» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPLII» 50% Off Thundershack 1 item<br>«SPLIV» Me N Eds Pizza<br>«SPLVI» Thundershack Gift Card<br>«SPLVIII» Free Sour Punch Stick<br>«SPLX» Free Soda<br>«SPLXII» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPLXIV» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPLXVI» Free Water<br>«SPLXVIII» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPLXX» 50% Off Thundershack 1 item<br>«SPLXXII» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPLXXIV» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPLXXVI» Club T-Bird Season Pass<br>«SPLXXVIII» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPLXXX» Free Sour Punch Stick<br>«SPLXXXII» 50% Off Thundershack 1 item<br>«SPLXXXIV» Free Fast Pass Token (Redeem at thundershack)<br>«SPLXXXVI» Free Sour Punch Stick<br>«SPLXXXVIII» Free Water<br>«SPXC» Free 6 Flags Magic Mountain Entrance Ticket<br>«SPXCII» Free Otter Pop<br>«SPXCIV» Club T-Bird Pass<br>«SPXCVI» 50% Off Thundershack 1 item<br>«SPXCVIII» Free Water<br>«SPC» Thundershack Spending Spree");

var AllKeys = ["«SPI»","«SPII»","«SPIII»","«SPIV»","«SPV»","«SPVI»","«SPVII»","«SPVIII»","«SPIX»","«SPX»","«SPXI»","«SPXII»","«SPXIII»","«SPXIV»","«SPXV»","«SPXVI»","«SPXVII»","«SPXVIII»","«SPXIX»","«SPXX»","«SPXXI»","«SPXXII»","«SPXXIII»","«SPXXIV»","«SPXXV»","«SPXXVI»","«SPXXVII»","«SPXXVIII»","«SPXXIX»","«SPXXX»","«SPXXXI»","«SPXXXII»","«SPXXXIII»","«SPXXXIV»","«SPXXXV»","«SPXXXVI»","«SPXXXVII»","«SPXXXVIII»","«SPXXXIX»","«SPXL»","«SPXLI»","«SPXLII»","«SPXLIII»","«SPXLIV»","«SPXLV»","«SPXLVI»","«SPXLVII»","«SPXLVIII»","«SPXLIX»","«SPL»","«SPLI»","«SPLII»","«SPLIII»","«SPLIV»","«SPLV»","«SPLVI»","«SPLVII»","«SPLVIII»","«SPLIX»","«SPLX»","«SPLXI»","«SPLXII»","«SPLXIII»","«SPLXIV»","«SPLXV»","«SPLXVI»","«SPLXVII»","«SPLXVIII»","«SPLXIX»","«SPLXX»","«SPLXXI»","«SPLXXII»","«SPLXXIII»","«SPLXXIV»","«SPLXXV»","«SPLXXVI»","«SPLXXVII»","«SPLXXVIII»","«SPLXXIX»","«SPLXXX»","«SPLXXXI»","«SPLXXXII»","«SPLXXXIII»","«SPLXXXIV»","«SPLXXXV»","«SPLXXXVI»","«SPLXXXVII»","«SPLXXXVIII»","«SPLXXXIX»","«SPXC»","«SPXCI»","«SPXCII»","«SPXCIII»","«SPXCIV»","«SPXCV»","«SPXCVI»","«SPXCVII»","«SPXCVIII»","«SPXCIX»","«SPC»"];

var UsedKeys =["«SPII»","«SPXCIV»","«SPLXVIII»"];
for (var i = 0; i < UsedKeys.length; i++) { 
var a = str.replace(UsedKeys[i],"✔️");
}
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = a; }
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the `UsedKeys` array into a single regexp that will replace all of them, using the `|` alternative operator. The `g` modifier makes it replace all occurrences.

```
var regex = new RegExp(UsedKeys.join('|'), 'g');
var newStr = str.replace(regex, "✔️");
```

You can then hide all the rest with:

```
newStr = newStr.replace(/«[^»]*»/g, " ");
```

Comment: The code I was using worked once I stopped setting another variable (a). Thanks for your help! How can I remove/replace all of the other keys with blanks? Use another array of all the non-used keys?

Comment: Everything else will match `/«[^»]*»/`, so you can just use that simple regexp to remove them.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular expression.

```
for (var i = 0; i < UsedKeys.length; i++) { 
    var regex = new RegExp(UsedKeys[i], 'g')
    var a = str.replace(regex, "✔️");
}
```

The 'g' means globally. So, replace all the occurences.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't seem to work. Did I sent it up wrong? [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpjOBQ?editors=1010)

Comment: You need to do `str = str.replace()`, otherwise you're not combining all the previous replacements.

Comment: @Barmar So don't create another variable?

Comment: That's correct. Each time through the loop it's doing the replacement on the original string, not the string with previous replacements.

Comment: So at the end, `a` just contains the last replacement, not all of them.