# JS conditional RegEx that removes different parts of a string between two delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string of text with HTML line breaks. Some of the `<br>` immediately follow a number between two delimiters `«...»` and some do not.

Here's the string:

`var str = ("«1»<br>«2»some text<br>«3»<br>«4»more text<br>«5»<br>«6»even more text<br>");`

I’m looking for a conditional regex that’ll remove the number and delimiters (ex. `«1»`) as well as the line break itself without removing all of the line breaks in the string.

So for instance, at the beginning of my example string, when the script encounters `»<br>` it’ll remove everything between and including the first `«` to the left, to `»<br>` (ex. `«1»<br>`). However it would not remove `«2»some text<br>`.

I’ve had [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313908/compare-an-array-to-a-string-and-replace-all-items-found-in-the-array-with-a-com/51314036#51314036) removing the entire number/delimiters (ex. `«1»`) using the following:

```
var regex = new RegExp(UsedKeys.join('|'), 'g');
var nextStr = str.replace(/«[^»]*»/g, " ");
```

I sure hope that makes sense.

Just to be super clear, when the string is rendered in a browser, I’d like to go ***from this…***

«1»

«2»some text

«3»

«4»more text

«5»

«6»even more text

***To this…***

«2»some text

«4»more text

«6»even more text

**Many thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing a subtlety here, if so I apologize. But it seems that you can just replace with the regex: `/«\d+»<br>/g`. This will replace all occurrences of a number between `«` & `»` followed by `<br>`

```js
var str = "«1»<br>«2»some text<br>«3»<br>«4»more text<br>«5»<br>«6»even more text<br>"

var newStr = str.replace(/«\d+»<br>/g, '')

console.log(newStr)
```

To match letters and digits you can use `\w` instead of `\d`

```js
var str = "«a»<br>«b»some text<br>«hel»<br>«4»more text<br>«5»<br>«6»even more text<br>"

var newStr = str.replace(/«\w+?»<br>/g, '')

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that does indeed work for numbers. How could I modify it to also work for letters or other characters between «  » ?

Comment: Works great Mark! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet assumes that the input within the brackets will always be a number but I think it solves the problem you're trying to solve.

```js
const str = "«1»<br>«2»some text<br>«3»<br>«4»more text<br>«5»<br>«6»even more text<br>";

console.log(str.replace(/(«(\d+)»<br>)/g, ""));
```

`/(«(\d+)»<br>)/g`

`«(\d+)»` Will match any brackets containing 1 or more digits in a row

If you would prefer to match alphanumeric you could use `«(\w+)»` or for any characters including symbols you could use `«([^»]+)»`

`<br>` Will match a line break

`//g` Matches globally so that it can find every instance of the substring

Basically we are only removing the bracketed numbers if they are immediately followed by a line break.

Comment: Awesome Nick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Why all the parenthesis?

Comment: To be fair I have a habit of providing capture cases for anything that I may consider capturing at some point in the future. They are wholly unnecessary in this application. Your solution is definitely the best if this is the only application the expression will be used for.

Comment: Thanks @NickAbbott - that wasn't a criticism, I was just curious if there was something going on that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @MarkMeyer and Nick Abbott You were both very helpful. Thank you. I'd accept both answers if I could!